# Translate CopyRecord from Berlin to XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, record, translate, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am trying to use the code from: https://github.com/hiro2233/mavlink_pascal

Which was written with RAD Studio Berlin.

It uses this function:

```
CopyRecord(@msg_data_PARAM_VALUE, packet_data, TypeInfo(mavlink_param_value_t));
```

Where:

```
  mavlink_param_value_t = record
    param_value: Single;
    param_count: Word;
    param_index: Word;
    param_id: array[0..15] of Byte;
    param_type: Byte;
  end;
msg_data_PARAM_VALUE:mavlink_param_value_t;
packet_data:System.TArray<System.Byte>;
```

I am using RAD Studio XE2 and it doesn't recognize this function.

I tried looking online but can't find anything.

Could someone help me figuring it out?

Cheers,
E.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`System.Move()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Move) instead:

```pascal
procedure THelpers.packet_msg_data_set(packet:System.TArray<System.Byte>; msg_id:UInt8; data_length:UInt8);
var
  packet_data:System.TArray<System.Byte>;
begin

  case msg_id of

    MAVLINK_MSG_ID.MAVLINK_MSG_ID_PARAM_VALUE:
    begin
      //SetLength(packet_data, data_length); // <-- redundant!
      packet_data:= Copy(packet,6,data_length);
      //CopyRecord(@msg_data_PARAM_VALUE, packet_data, TypeInfo(mavlink_param_value_t));
      Move(packet_data[0], msg_data_PARAM_VALUE, SizeOf(msg_data_PARAM_VALUE));
    end;

    MAVLINK_MSG_ID.MAVLINK_MSG_ID_HEARTBEAT:
    begin
      //SetLength(packet_data, data_length); // <-- redundant!
      packet_data:= Copy(packet,6,data_length);
      //CopyRecord(@msg_data_HEARTBEAT, packet_data, TypeInfo(mavlink_heartbeat_t));
      Move(packet_data[0], msg_data_HEARTBEAT, SizeOf(msg_data_HEARTBEAT));
    end;
  end;

end;
```

The code in question is copying bytes from a `TArray<Byte>` to 1 of 2 possible `record`s, and all of the fields in those `record`s are fundamental types only, there are no pointers or refcounts involved. So I don't know why the author chose to use `CopyRecord()` to rely on RTTI to copy those bytes, that function should not be used directly at all.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy. I'll try to see if I can use it. His project example is very unclear.